# Removing some strings in a word in PHP within an array

Tags: php

I am have retrieved all the file contents from a directory. It prints the file contents name from an array. However I want only a portion of the file content name. Any idea how can I achieve this? I have tried using the following:

The file contents from the directory has format: **pdb101m.ent.gz** , **pdb102l.ent.gz**
I want to retrieve only the **101m** and **102l**

```
<?php
$dir = "C:/Users/Desktop/EAD/PDB/";

$files = array();

$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    $files[] = $filename;
}


foreach($files as $ex){

    echo str_replace('pdb.ent.gz', ' ', $ex). '<br>';

}


?>
```

Please help. Grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [substr()](http://www.php.net/substr) function:

```
echo substr('pdb101m.ent.gz',3,4); // Outputs: 101m
echo substr('pdb102l.ent.gz',3,4); // Outputs: 102l
```

So:

```
foreach($files as $ex){

    echo substr($ex, 3,4). '<br>';

}
```

**Edit: Update my answer attending the OP new request:**
 So in your query you should use:

```
foreach ($files as $ex) {

    $search = substr($ex, 3, 4);

    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT `pdb_code` FROM pdb WHERE `pdb_code` <> "' . $search . '" LIMIT 6';

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $pdb[] = $row['pdb_code'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Nacho, I get the output as `101m.en`

Comment: Try again @Razoir I corrected the third argument of the substr function.

Comment: `foreach($files as $ex){

          $search = substr($ex,3,4);
      
      $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT `pdb_code` FROM pdb WHERE `pdb_code` <>' .`$search`. 'LIMIT 6';
      
      $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        $pdb[] = $row['pdb_code'];
      } 
    }`

Comment: I have entered the $search in an SQL Query, but its not working.. 
Can you help ?

Comment: I updated my answer @Razoir to your request. Be careful using mysql functions: they are deprecated in latest PHP versions and its use is discouraged. Use PDO or mysqli functions ;-)

Comment: @Razoir please, upvote the answer as well if it was useful to you.

Comment: I am unable to upvote it bro.. I guess I do not have enough reputations.. I've marked it as accepted though. Thanks bro

Comment: Oh.. I didn't know.  Ok, don't worry. Glad to help you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always `pdb` at the beggining and `.ent.gz` at the end you can do simply:

```
echo substr('pdb101m.ent.gz',3,-7);
```

Negative value of third parameter in [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) means

> that many characters will be omitted from the end of string